# Material UI : Customized Tabs styles are not working

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to create customized tabs same as which is explained in material UI documentation.
https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/
[Customized Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TJX0.png)
I am trying to achieve this functionality using material Ui and React JS CDN and writing in the single HTML file.
Below are CDNs:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have changed standard styles for tabsRoot. However, styles are not getting updated on Tabs.

Below is the code which i am using but currently it is not working . CDN may has error. I am unable to solve

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>My page</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@latest/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@latest/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@latest/babel.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
 
const {
  AppBar,
  Button,
  colors,
  createMuiTheme,
  CssBaseline,
  Dialog,
  DialogActions,
  DialogContent,
  DialogContentText,
  DialogTitle,
  Icon,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  Typography,
  withStyles,
  Paper,
  Tabs,
  Tab,
  Slide,
  SwipeableViews,
  PropTypes
} = window['material-ui'];

function TabContainer(props) {
  return (
    <Typography  component="div" style={{ padding: 8 * 3 }}>
      {props.children}  
    </Typography>
  );
};

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
tabsRoot: {
    borderBottom: '0px solid #e8e8e8',
  },
});
 
 class ARDASHBOARD extends React.Component<{}>{
   state = {
    value: 0,
  };

  handleChange = (event, value) => {
    this.setState({ 
  value
 });
  };

 render() 
 {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state; 
 const maxSteps = 4;
 const activeStep = 1 ;
 return (
  <div>
     <Paper >
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
    indicatorColor="secondary"
          textColor="primary"
    fullWidth
    scrollable
        >
          <Tab   label={
   <div>
    <Typography variant="caption">
     DSO
    </Typography>
    <Typography variant="title">
     28
    </Typography>
   </div>
   } />
          <Tab  label={
      <div>
        <Typography variant="caption">
          CEI
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="title">
          29
        </Typography>
      </div>
   } />
    <Tab  label={
      <div>
        <Typography variant="caption" >
          ADP
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="title">
          31
        </Typography>
      </div>
   } />
    <Tab 
    label={
      <div>
        <Typography variant="caption">
          ADL
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="title">
          38
        </Typography>
      </div>
   } />
        </Tabs>
      </Paper> 
  </div> ); 
 }};
  
 var ARDASHBOARD1 = withStyles(styles)(ARDASHBOARD);
ReactDOM.render(<ARDASHBOARD1 />, document.getElementById('root'));
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = "test result";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please paste the code that you are trying?

Comment: Hi , I have edited post with required information

Answer (score 0):

Okay just as I suspected, there seems to be an issue with Material UI when trying to use it with a CDN, especially through JSFiddle or through Stack Snippets. I think the importing/requires are incorrect. I've been trying to use Material UI through a CDN for multiple answers to the [material-ui questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/material-ui) and always get an error.

Your best bet is to create a small React project locally that has material-ui installed.